# looking for a certain quote/saying about winning, luck and practicing

Tags: quotes, popular-refrains

I'm not sure if this the correct forum, but I can't seem to be able to google it so you guys are my only hope.

I know there is a saying that means something like "**you have to be lucky to win, but it's usually the people who train a lot that win**" or "**the winner got lucky, but unless you practice a lot you won't get lucky**", but I don't really recall the exact wording or who said it.

Comment: Help me english.stackexchange.com you're my only hope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you’re thinking of the professional golfer, possibly Arnold Palmer, who said *The more I practice, the luckier I get*.

Comment: Thanks! According to google, it is dubious who to credit the quote to, though.

Comment: @Kimvais - Quite. Gary Player seems to be popular, but I also see it attributed to studio head (but probably also golfer) Samuel Goldwyn. When I first heard it in the wild personally back in the 70's, I believe it was attributed to Chi-Chi Rodríguez as part of a parable about racism.

Answer (score 5):

In a lecture at the University of Lille on 7 December 1854, [Louis Pasteur said](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Louis_Pasteur):

> Dans les champs de l'observation le hasard ne favorise que les esprits préparés.

Which has been translated several ways:

> In the fields of observation chance favors only the prepared mind.
>   Chance favors the prepared mind.
>   Fortune favors the prepared mind.

That may not be exactly what you are looking for, but your saying could have been derived from this.